# What is the proper server-side mitigation for the Lucky13 vulnerability (CVE-2013-0169) on a Windows server?

Tags: encryption, tls, cryptography, vulnerability, windows-server

The [testssl.sh](https://testssl.sh/) tool stated that a server I tested is vulnerable to the Lucky13 ([CVE-2013-0169](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2013-0169)) vulnerability. Below the testssl.sh output:

```
###########################################################
testssl.sh
###########################################################
Testing for LUCKY13 vulnerability 
LUCKY13 (CVE-2013-0169) VULNERABLE, uses cipher block chaining (CBC) ciphers
```

I'd say that upgrading OpenSSL would fix it. But, this is Windows Server 2012, so no OpenSSL there. What would be the proper fix in order to mitigate this?

I was thinking about:

- Disabling TLS 1.0 entirely;
- Removing all cipher block chaining (CBC) ciphers.

Are there other mitigations for Lucky13 and why did Microsoft not just fix this with a security patch?

Comment: You ran a bash shell script on a Windows server? It looks like only open source software is affected - PolarSSL, OpenSSL & OpenJDK.

Comment: I would do as you suggest for LUCKY13 - You might find some issues with disabling TLS 1.0 though as I am sure you are aware of already. Have you reordered the cipher suites from the default as well?

Comment: @DKNUCKLES although that would technically be possible with cygwin, I did not. I ran a bash script from another machine (Linux) against a Windows server.

Comment: @ISMSDEV No I have not reordered the default cipher suites. But, isn't the client allowed to give a preferred order anyway?

Comment: You want to re-order them defiantly (one of the first harderning things I tend to do). This tool makes it dead easy: https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto  (You can do this directly in the registry if you can't (don't want to) execute this on the server)

Comment: @BobOrtiz A client gives the ones it supports, but the server picks the most suitable (secure) based on your cipher suite order (as long as its in the list from the client).

Comment: Also make sure you disable all the ones you have no reason to support (e.g. RC4 etc)

Comment: @BobOrtiz Still, doesn't appear that Windows crypto is vulnerable to this. Vulnerable software listed in that link you posted only lists the aforementioned products in my previous comment as being vulnerable.

Comment: @DKNUCKLES - My research seems to be showing the same. There is a possibility the scanner thinks its LUCKY13 but is something else due to the ciphersuites available. A hardening of those available ciphersuites and a re-run of the scan will help to rule that in or out.

Comment: @DKNUCKLES: the RHUL researchers only looked at open-source, see the website; I don't think anyone but MS knows if Windows was or is vulnerable. (1) OpenSSL is available on Windows and so are servers using it; AFAIK only IIS, Exchange and RDS (and dotnet?) use schannl. (2) The actual vuln is suites using (HMAC-then-)CBC _and_ a tiny timing effect in the code; I don't believe for a second a shell tool checks the second half. (3) Removing all CBC suites effectively removes TLS 1.0 _and_ 1.1 because with RC4 broken much worse you are left with only GCM which requires 1.2.

Comment: Related on testssl github site: (unanswered): https://github.com/drwetter/testssl.sh/issues/789

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @StackzOfZtuff, this was a false-positive of the `testssl.sh` tool.

Confirmed here: https://github.com/drwetter/testssl.sh/issues/789.